# How to target a file (a path to it) in Java/JavaFX

Tags: file, path, media, javafx-2

It might be a simple one, but i can't seem to get it to work. I am making a video player in JavaFX but I don't know how to target the file that is going to be played (I don't know the correct syntax). Thank you in advance for your help. Here's a sample of code that i'm trying to run>

```
    Media media = new Media("trailers/trailer.mp4");
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
    MediaView view = new MediaView(player);
```

btw, the file is in the project folder, then trailers/trailer.mp4. Oh, and I'm running Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your file into the sources folder and load it as a resource:

```
Media media = new Media(getClass().getResource("trailer.mp4"));
```

or use the full path

```
Media media = new Media("file://c:/trailers/trailer.mp4"));
```

Also, note that JavaFX 2.0 supports only FLV codec. For mp4 (with H.264 codec) you need to use JavaFX 2.1 or later.

Comment: Just in case, an Update. JavaFX 8.0 and JavaFX 9.0 do support MP4 with H.264 as well.

Answer (score 7):

1 Use this if media source file in same project package.

```
 Media media = new Media("trailer.mp4");
```

2 Use this if media source file in same project sub package [Packages with name "trailers" in project main package]

```
 Media media = new Media("trailers/trailer.mp4");
```

3 Use this if media source file is other location [Using full path].

```
 Media media = new Media("file:///e:/trailers/trailer.mp4");
```

OR

```
 Media media = new Media("file:///E:/trailers/trailer.mp4");
```

Note: should use 3 slash i.e. "file:///" to avoid error "MediaException: MEDIA_INACCESSIBLE : e/E"

Answer (score 3):

If you want to load media from your project package:

```
File file=new File("trailer.mp4");
Media media=new Media(file.toURI().toString())
```