# How to Change the icon on the title bar of a stage in java fx 2.0 of my application

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, stage

I have tried the

```
 stage.getIcons().add(new Image("attuncore.jpg"));
```

But I don't know what is going wrong ..

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Append the error message to your question if any.

Comment: I'm guessing attuncore.jpg was not found.

Comment: The problem is that i am not getting any error.

Comment: There is a similar question in SO.Check out the below Link [JavaFX Application Icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121991/javafx-application-icon?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 55):

Full program for starters :) This program set Stack Overflow Icon.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StackoverflowIcon extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        // set icon
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image("/path/to/stackoverflow.jpg"));
        stage.setTitle("Wow!! Stackoverflow Icon");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Output Screnshot**

[image: JavaFX Screenshot]

> Updated for JavaFX 8

No need to change the code. It still works fine. Tested and verified in Java 1.8(1.8.0_45). Path can be set to local or remote both are supported.

```
stage.getIcons().add(new Image("/path/to/javaicon.png"));
```

OR

```
stage.getIcons().add(new Image("https://example.com/javaicon.png"));
```

[image]

Hope it helps. Thanks!!

Comment: I wonder how come no body up voted you, thanks for the answer

Comment: Does the size matter? c:

Comment: Perfect answer, and size does not appear to matter.

Answer (score 5):

You can load the image from the classpath like this:

```
new Image(XYZ.class.getResourceAsStream("/xyz.png"))
```

where XYZ is some classname (maybe the one you're loading the image from) and xyz.png is the name of your image file, put in a directory (or JAR file) included in your classpath.

If you like to put the image next to the source file, you have to omit the / character. Your IDE needs to be configured to copy ressources (like *.png) from src to bin directory, then. But this is supposed to be the standard behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

For those who had a problem with:

> Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found

The best solution is to make new package i.e image.icons and move there your .png image. Then you just need to write:

```
Image image = new Image("/image/icons/list.png");
primaryStage.getIcons().add(image);
```

I hope this helps somebody!

Comment: `"file:image/icons/list.png"` is another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Does your image have correct size? Javadoc states:

> public final ObservableList getIcons()
>
> Gets the icon images to be used in the window decorations and when
> minimized. The images should be different sizes of the same image and
> the best size will be chosen, eg. 16x16, 32,32.

Comment: Thanks Sergey but image size doesn't affect that i think so. but yeah i finally got the solution by setting the properties of standalone working directory to package where my main and image is placed.

Comment: oh, image finding was a problem, great you've find out it. There were a bunch of similar issues, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062270/how-to-target-a-file-a-path-to-it-in-java-javafx

Answer (score 1):

The solution i found by setting the properties of standalone working directory to package where my main and image is placed.

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget to do the import

```
import javafx.scene.image.Image;

Image icon = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("myicon.png"));
stage.getIcons().add(icon);
```

Replace `"myicon.png"` with your icon. In this case it's in the same folder as your java class.