# Appliacation icon on javafx

Tags: java, javafx, icons

I can't add an icon to my application with this code

```
stage2.getIcons().add(new Image("/home/icon.jpg"));
```

I really need help ? 
Thank you

Comment: A similar question with quite a few tips is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10275841/5956451)

Comment: I have already seen this question !! but my code is similar to the answers of that -duplicated question- and it doesn't work for me !!

Comment: Well, it boils down to the question where your image is. Is it on the class path, or is it stored elsewhere? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12827704/5956451) answer.