# JavaFX 2 Media from file with a relative path

Tags: eclipse, javafx-2

I'm trying to create a JavaFX 2 Media Instance with a relative path (in Eclipse). I've tried it by writing this:

```
Media media= new Media("file://test.flv");
```

This gives me a MediaException of type MEDIA_INACCESSIBLE. The file I'm trying to load is located in my eclipse project root folder.

I am aware of the answer to this question [How to target a file (a path to it) in Java/JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062270/how-to-target-a-file-a-path-to-it-in-java-javafx) but this only covers loading a file with an absolute path or as a resource.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1.** if you want to load media from path relative to your **`.java/.class`** file you have to use resource loading. Nobody else can be sure about their location.

Just add `.toExternalForm()` if you don't like raw resources for some reason:

```
Media media= new Media(getClass().getResource("test.flv").toExternalForm());
```

**2.** if you want to load media relative to **workdir** of your application you can try next:

```
Media media = new Media(new File("test.flv").toURI().toString());
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey (once again) part 2 of your answer is what I was asking for.