# Finding all the files of a certain extension in a project's source folder

Tags: java, file, mp3

Hello I am trying to retrieve the names of all the files of the type `.mp3` from a source folder(below) [image]

Below is the code I am using to differentiate the file type and add to the list. However I do not know which parameter I should enter into the `directory` it should be `music` folder however I do not know how to represent this.

```
    File dir = new File("");
    String[] files = dir.list(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp3");
        };
    });
    for(int a = 0; a < files.length; a++)
    {
        musicList.add(files[a]);
    }
```

Comment: Go into your workspace, and get the path to the music folder (right click it), and then in your code do this: File dir = new File("/path/to/music/folder");

Comment: @Adam Ren which type of application you are using, i means Spring, Servlet or Simple java Application

Comment: @JayPrakashKumar Its a javafx application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
List<String> result = Files.find(Paths.get("music"), 100,
    (p, a) -> p.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp3"))
    .map(path -> path.toString())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Submitted edit for your post basically should be `.\\music` in `Paths.get();`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Servlet :

```
ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("music");
```

if using Spring :

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("music").getFile());
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

For javafx see this:

[How to target a file (a path to it) in Java/JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062270/how-to-target-a-file-a-path-to-it-in-java-javafx)